# How do I delete duplicates data and the same time remove value which not in a new table

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have two table `table_new` and `table_old`

table_old

```
ID      email_address  full_name  address
-----------------------------------------
1       a@b.com        john      street 1
2       b@b.com        peter     street 2
3       c@b.com        david     street 3
```

table_new

```
ID      email_address
----------------------
1       b@b.com
2       c@b.com
3       d@b.com
4       e@b.com
5       f@b.com
...     ....
300     xyz@xux.com
```

**Questions :**

How do I copy the email address from `table_new` to `table_old` with some statement below

1. If in `table_old` already exists an email address from `table_new` ignore it.
2. If in `table_new` does not exists an email address from `table_old` delete it.

So the result should be

`table_old`

```
ID      email_address  full_name  address
-----------------------------------------
1       b@b.com        peter     street 2
2       c@b.com        david     street 3
3       d@b.com
4       e@b.com
5       f@b.com
...     ....
300     xyz@xux.com
```

Let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it can be done in two queries.

```
delete from old_table where email_address not in 
(select email_address from new_table)

Insert into old_table (email_address) select email_address 
from new_table where email_address not in (select email_address from old_table)
```

Assuming id is an autoincrement key, otherwise id can be inserted and selected, along with email address.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Insert into old_table (email_address, full_name, address)
(select email_address, '' as full_name, '' as address
from new_table where email_address not in (select email_address from old_table) group by  new_table.email_address
);
```